# How do I set the default phone uploads folder for Google Photos?

Tags: photos, google-photos, backup, online-backup

I have been backing up my photos to Google Photos ever since I lost them all a while back. But I would like to add a few directories to sort out the photos since I am about to add more photos. Though I don't want to get them all mixed up with my current phone uploads.

So where do I set the default location where my phone uploads to, so I can create a "Phone Uploads" then create a "Photography" folder?

If this isn't possible, what would be the best way to sort the photos so it is easier manage?